# What is the name of this black-ochre striped snake?

Tags: species-identification, snake

I've seen the following snake (?) near Calvi (on Corsica):

[image]

I guess it was about 50cm long.

What is the name of this type of snake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great find!  Based on the picture and location, I believe this is the **Corsican grass snake** (*[Natrix natrix corsa](http://www.iucnredlist.org/details/14368/1)*).  It is a pretty rare subspecies, and is listed on Annex IV of the European Union Habitat and Species Directive.  Worth mentioning that it's nonvenomous.

[image: Natrix natrix corsa]

Photo cred to [Frank Deschandol/Philippe Sabine](http://www.deschandol-sabine.com/pages-aperture/serpents/corsa/grand-19.html)

Unfortunately, I was not able to find too much more info on this subspecies.  I know *Natrix natrix* are pretty widespread throughout Eurasia, but this subspecies is much more restricted.